# Preserving asymptotic stability of ODE under perturbation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system $\dot{x} = [A+\epsilon B(t)]x$ where all of the eigenvalues of $A$ has real part strictly less than $0$, and $B(t)$ is continuous with period $1$. We want to show that for small $|\epsilon|$, $\lim_{t\to \infty} |x(t)|=0$. Since the system $\dot{x}=Ax$ is asymptotically stable, my initial instinct was to show that $F(t,x) =\epsilon B(t) x$ is a small enough perturbation to preserve asymptotically stability. In particular, if it is locally Lipschitz (which it is) and satisfies $\lim_{x\to 0} \sup_{t} \frac{||F(t,x)||}{||x||}=0$, then we're good. However, it doesn't satisfy the latter condition, so I don't think this is the right train of thought.

Since $A$ is constant and $B(t)$ has period $1$, then the matrix $A+\epsilon B(t)$ also has period $1$, I think that Floquet theory is the right way to go about this. I'm sure I need to look at the characteristic multipliers and show they have negative real part, but I'm not sure how to get started with that. I know I can right the fundamental solution $X(t) = P(t)e^{Rt}$ for some $1$-periodic matrix $P(t)$ and some matrix $R$, but I'm not sure how to proceed.